# Is it possible to edit the granularity of the Moment#to output?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

With MomentJS's `Moment#to` method, is there any way that I can control the output at all?

```js
var opens = moment('Tue 8:00:00am', 'ddd h:mm:ssa')

var now1 = moment('Tue 7:43:30am', 'ddd h:mm:ssa')
console.log(now1.to(opens))  // in 17 minutes

var now2 = moment('Tue 7:43:31am', 'ddd h:mm:ssa')
console.log(now2.to(opens))  // in 16 minutes
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.17.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I'd like for `now2.to(opens)` to ignore seconds while comparing, so it would return "in 17 minutes".

I have a feeling that that's not possible, since the [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/to/) don't list any parameters that are applicable.

`Moment#isBefore` and friends take a second optional parameter that lets you limit the granularity of the comparison (eg, `Moment#isBefore(otherMoment, 'minute')` will ignore seconds and milliseconds when comparing.

---

**Edit:** My end goal is to only have the "in N minutes" message change when the minute changes, instead of at 31 seconds.

In my example above, I have "in 17 minutes" when the source moment is at :30, and "in 16 minutes" at :31.

---

**Edit 2:** In my application, my left-hand moment is taken from `moment()`, so it inherits from the environment. My right-hand moment is parsed from a string without seconds. I'm not sure how relevant this information is, which is why I left it out of the original question.

Comment: Not sure I'm following your question. Do you want to control how the end result is displayed or do you want to control what information is passed/processed by the `to()` method?

Comment: I'm aiming to prevent `.to()` from doing that "rounding" behavior where it changes the "in N minutes" number at 31 seconds; I'd like for it to only change when the minute changes. I'll try to edit the question to make that more obvious.

Comment: If you don't want seconds compared, then don't give it seconds to compare, cut them out before passing it into moment.

Comment: Huh. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: @AmericanSlime I wound up setting `.seconds(0)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official way to customize how moment displays relative time is using [`relativeTimeRounding`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-rounding/) and [`relativeTimeThreshold`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) (and [`relativeTime`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) key of `moment.updateLocale` if needed).

In your case, to get the desired output, you can set rounding function to `Math.floor` (default `Math.round`) and set second threshold to 60 (default 45).

Here a live sample:

```js
var opens = moment('Tue 8:00:00am', 'ddd h:mm:ssa');
var now1 = moment('Tue 7:43:30am', 'ddd h:mm:ssa');
var now2 = moment('Tue 7:43:31am', 'ddd h:mm:ssa');
var now3 = moment('Tue 7:44:01am', 'ddd h:mm:ssa');

console.log(now1.to(opens));  // in 17 minutes
console.log(now2.to(opens));  // in 16 minutes
console.log(now3.to(opens));  // in 16 minutes

// Change relative time rounding
moment.relativeTimeRounding(Math.floor);
// Set 1 minute = 60 seconds (default 45)
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 60);

console.log(now1.to(opens));  // in 16 minutes
console.log(now2.to(opens));  // in 16 minutes
console.log(now3.to(opens));  // in 15 minutes
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh wow. That looks like exactly what I was hoping to find! Thanks! I'll try it out tomorrow.

Comment: @HawkenRives did you checked? Is everything fine? Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! "Tomorrow" turned into "in a few months", but I just checked and it works _perfectly_. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by changing the transformation parser. If you don't pass seconds information, the .to method won't take them into account.

```
var opens = moment('Tue 8:00:00am', 'ddd h:mm')

var now1 = moment('Tue 7:43:30am', 'ddd h:mm')
console.log(now1.to(opens))  // in 17 minutes

var now2 = moment('Tue 7:43:31am', 'ddd h:mm')
console.log(now2.to(opens))  // in 17 minutes
```

Comment: Doesn't changing the parser just make the moment constructor take the "current" second from the environment, instead?

Comment: Nevermind, I was incorrect. That sets `.seconds()` to 0. Unfortunately, my actual left-hand moment is taken from the environment, so it will have seconds set.

Comment: The seconds are available in the moment constructor, but won't be taken into account by the manipulation. If you console.log your now1 or now2 you'll find a _pf object. This contains the parsedDateParts and unusedInput Arrays.

All of moments transforming methods will take those into account.