# moment update time from now string display

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment and using the [`fromNow()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) method.

```
moment.updateLocale("en", {
  relativeTime: {
    s: "seconds",
    m: "a minute",
    mm: "%d minutes",
    h: "an hour",
    hh: "%d hours",
    d: "a day",
    dd: "%d days",
    M: "a month",
    MM: "%d months",
    y: "a year",
    yy: "%d years"
  }
});


let value = "2017-09-29T10:50:00.000000+0100";
let dateDisplay = moment(value).fromNow();
//this logs in an hour although it is in 50 mins
console.log(dateDisplay);
```

I believe that this is expected as in the docs on the link provided from above it states that 45 - 89 mins will show `an hour ago`.

Does anyone know how to update this so that it will work on actual time - i.e. `50 minutes ago/in 50 minutes`? (depending on whether the time has passed or is in the future)

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/ lists what values will result in what output. 45 to 89 minutes -> “an hour ago.” It doesn’t say anywhere there that this was somehow configurable. So I think you might have to write your own function.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42513276/4131048), you can use [`relativeTimeThreshold`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`relativeTimeThreshold`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/)

As the docs says:

> `duration.humanize` has thresholds which define when a unit is considered a minute, an hour and so on. For example, by default more than 45 seconds is considered a minute, more than 22 hours is considered a day and so on. To change those cutoffs use `moment.relativeTimeThreshold(unit, limit)` where unit is one of `s`, `m`, `h`, `d`, `M`.

In your case, you can use `moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);`. Here a live sample:

```js
let value = "2017-09-29T11:00:00.000000+0100";
let dateDisplay = moment(value).fromNow();
console.log(dateDisplay);

moment.updateLocale("en", {
  relativeTime: {
    s: "seconds",
    m: "a minute",
    mm: "%d minutes",
    h: "an hour",
    hh: "%d hours",
    d: "a day",
    dd: "%d days",
    M: "a month",
    MM: "%d months",
    y: "a year",
    yy: "%d years"
  }
});

moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);

dateDisplay = moment(value).fromNow();
//this logs in an hour although it is in 50 mins
console.log(dateDisplay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```